# Is there a way to check that the room or namespace is not present in socketio

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am making a simple chat website with NodeJS and socketio.

When the user opens the page, they see two options, one to create a chat room and other to join a chat room. If the password entered in the join room field is not valid, then how can we check that the room or namespace doesn't exist

Comment: on the `socket` instance there is a `rooms` property you can check. on the `io` instance you can check `io.sockets.rooms` should give you every room created. Check here: https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-socket-instance/#Socket-rooms

Comment: @halilcakar in client side or server side

Comment: As link suggests it's server-socket-instance :)